# Some power armor pieces are missing until I hop in?

Tags: fallout-4

When I entered a power armour suit, I noticed that some pieces were missing, it looks like I only have a few parts on, and the fusion core will just be hovering.

However, when I exit, I find that all my pieces are on. What's the problem? I'm on Xbox One by the way.

Comment: Can you take some screenshots and include those in your post? That will give us a better understanding of what is going on with your problems.

Comment: Maybe the parts are just broken ?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a piece of armor breaks (durability zero), it will be removed from the armor suit and placed in your inventory. You can't add it back to the power armor suit without repairing it at the power armor workbench. I suspect this is what's happening here.

Some mods might cause strange graphic bugs to wearable items, so if you are using any mods, start by disabling them and see if the problem persists.